# Creating controls with unique IDs dynamically inside an ASP.NET repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a list of files (stored in a database) that I would like the user to be able to upload in asynchronous callbacks.

I have got as far as displaying AJAX Control Toolkit's [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) controls next to the name of each file I'm expecting:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SourceTables" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LongName")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ajax:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

All of these async upload controls will end up calling the same method in code behind, which is fine, but when I come to save the file I need some way to identify which control is causing the postback (i.e. which of the several files has just been uploaded). However, I have been unable to set the ID dynamically inside the repeater (I believe it is only possible from code behind).

Clearly this doesn't work:

```
<ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShortName")%> runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
```

Is there another way I can set the ID of each of the upload controls dynamically inside the repeater (or otherwise) or another approach I can take?

Comment: So, is setting it inside the code an option?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that while adding the controls in the repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add controls dynamically in "ItemDatabound" event of the repeater.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely the best/easiest way to do it. Thanks Sreekanth.

Answer (score 0):

You can't  bind the `ID` property of controls. You will need to create the control in code behind and add it to the repeater.

Example:

```
protected void GridDataBind(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        IEnumerable list = PremiumUnitFees.PremiumAmenities.ObtainFeesForProject(IntranetUser.Current.ProjectId);
        foreach (PremiumUnitFees.PremiumAmenities feature in list) {
            e.Row.Cells(3).Controls.Add(new CheckBox {
                ID = feature.Id.ToString(),
                Text = feature.NickName,
                Checked = PremiumUnitFees.PremiumUnitView.IsUnitPremium(feature.Id, Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id")))
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the daft question, but how do you create a control in code behind and add it to the repeater? I can't find any examples.

Comment: @Chris I'll update my answer. It was pretty basic due to my answering you via my phone on the train, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling the postback events?

If you are using the *UploadedComplete* event of the **AsyncFileUpload** control, you get the uploaded file through the **AsyncFileUploadEventArgs** object.

You could also cast **sender** to your **AsyncFileUpload** control and then get the file through the **PostedFile** property.

```
 protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
 {
     string savePath = MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(e.filename));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - yes exactly that's what I'm doing. But I don't want to save using the same filename (I don't trust the incoming filename) so I would like to identify which control is doing the postback and (based on that) save with a particular filename etc.

Comment: Okay - the sender object passed to the event handler, is actually the AsyncFileUpload control. So you should be able to cast it and use it however you like. In similar scenarios I've been saving the file with a guid as filename, but with the same file extension as the incoming filename.

Comment: You could also traverse your way up the control tree using the Parent property of the sender control, to get to the DataItem you're using in the databinding.

Comment: I've managed to do what I wanted by traversing up using the Parent property - thanks very much for that idea. I don't think I'm doing it well though - the only useful property I'm able to get this way is ItemIndex. Given this, and performing my DB query again to get the array that the repeater is bound to, I can calculate what is in the RepeaterItem. Is there any way to access the DataItem with bound data through the Parent property, though, as you said? If this isn't clear I'll rewrite with more detail. Many thanks again Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
  <ajax:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" id="afuMyUpload" ClientIDMode="AutoID" OnClientUploadComplete="MyFunction" />



   foreach (Control c in SourceTables.Items)
   {
        var myUpload = c.FindControl("afuMyUpload") as AsyncFileUpload;
        //Do stuff with your control
   }
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do something like this to set the IDs to a property of the DataItem of the repeater that created them?

Comment: @Chris Do you mean the server or the client Ids? Setting the ServerId's inside a Repeater doesn't really do much, as you can't access them directly. You'd still have to look through them like above.